# Mysql: how to “group by” over a range?

Tags: mysql

If I have a table like this:

```
pkey   age   weight
----   ---    -----
   1     8     33
   2     5     41
   3    12     20
   4    12     24
   5    22     69
```

What query can I use to group by age and weight ranges

for eg:

```
pkey   age   weight
----   ---    -----
   1     1-10     31-40
   2     1-10     41-50
   3    11-20     11-20
   4    11-20     21-30
   5    21-30     61-70
```

Comment: So what is your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT pkey, CASE
   WHEN age BETWEEN 1 AND 10 THEN "1-10"
   WHEN age BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN "11-20"
   WHEN age BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN "21-30"
   WHEN age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN "31-40"
   WHEN age BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN "41-50"
   WHEN age BETWEEN 51 AND 60 THEN "51-60"
   WHEN age BETWEEN 61 AND 70 THEN "61-70"
   WHEN age BETWEEN 71 AND 80 THEN "71-80"
   WHEN age BETWEEN 81 AND 90 THEN "81-90"
   WHEN age BETWEEN 91 AND 100 THEN "91-100"
   WHEN age BETWEEN 101 AND 110 THEN "101-110" 
   ELSE ">110" END AS ageRange,
   CASE
   WHEN weight BETWEEN 1 AND 10 THEN "1-10"
   WHEN weight BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN "11-20"
   WHEN weight BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN "21-30"
   WHEN weight BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN "31-40"
   WHEN weight BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN "41-50"
   WHEN weight BETWEEN 51 AND 60 THEN "51-60"
   WHEN weight BETWEEN 61 AND 70 THEN "61-70"
   WHEN weight BETWEEN 71 AND 80 THEN "71-80"
   WHEN weight BETWEEN 81 AND 90 THEN "81-90"
   ELSE ">90" END AS weightRange
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `GROUP BY`, instead try something like this:

```
select pkey, 
    IF (age < 11, "1-10", IF (age < 21, "11-20", IF (age < 31, "21-30", "..."))),
    IF (weight < 11, "1-10", IF (weight < 21, "11-20", IF (weight < 31, "21-30", "...")))
from table
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, if less typing's your thing...

```
SELECT pkey
     , CONCAT(FLOOR(age/10)*10+1,'-',CEILING(age/10)*10) age_range 
     , CONCAT(FLOOR(weight/10)*10+1,'-',CEILING(weight/10)*10) weight_range 
  FROM my_table;
```